# How do I populate these fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

If you go to this website https://www.cameralends.com/?utm_source=hackernews you can click the various drop downs. What I'd like to know is how do you populate those fields with data?

e.g. There are different camera models you can choose from etc...

I know that using a code like:

```
<% = a.select :categories, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :include_blank => true', :multiple => "multiple" %>
```

Will display them, but how do I populate the categories initially?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a default set of values to your application, you should use some [seeds](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data).

See this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) to learn more about them.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways do achieve this. Take your pick from these helpers, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate them from the beginning you just have to pass the desired value to `options_for_select()`, for instance:

```
<% options = Category.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] } %>

<%= a.select :categories, options_for_select(options, @my_object.category_id), 
             :include_blank => true', :multiple => "multiple" %>
```

In that case, the preselected value will be `@my_object.category_id`, supposing `@my_object` is the object edited by the form.